# How to plot time series data with time data is number of seconds passed

Tags: plot, time-series, gnuplot

I have the following data and I want to plot it.

```
#time,load
10,35965.67
15,35233.82
20,35239.05
25,37188.61
30,36622.32
35,36538.27
....
3000,36305.84
```

On every line, the first column is the number of seconds has passed. The second column is the total of transactions every 5 seconds.

I want to plot so that:

- x-axis: time. for example 10/15/20/25 ...
- y-axis: transactions.

Here is my config:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal png size 900,400
set title "Transaction/second graph"
set ylabel "Transactions"
set xlabel "Seconds"
set xdata time
set format x "%s"
set key left top
set grid
plot "output.txt" using 0:1 with lines lw 2 lt 3 title 'tps'
```

So the image which Gnuplot generated is:

[image]

This image is reversed in the axis. I tried different solutions such as `plot using 1:0` but I received an exception. Moreover, it looks like the data is not correct. I don't know what value for 0/60/120 ...

Comment: You want 1:2, not 0:1. But you need to replace `,` by a space first.

Comment: @choroba The tutorial which I read show "1:2" too. But I tried that and I received an exception. That why I change to "0:1" (my bad). I think it is because of the separator. But I have set the separator to comma. Is there any way I use commas?

Comment: What exception? Setting the datafile separator should work.

Comment: ```plot "output.txt" using 1:2 with lines lw 2 lt 3 title 'tps'  line 0: x range is invalid``` Here is my exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your data in seconds and just want to display seconds, I don't see a reason why changing data to timedata with `set xdata time`. Unless you want to display it as hours:minutes:seconds or days.

So simply use:

```
plot "output.txt" u 1:2 w l lw 2 lt 3 title 'tps'
```

It doesn't hurt if you start your code with `reset session`. With this ranges and numbers and other persistent settings which could cause unexpected results are reset. If I don't use `set output` the output file will not be closed and have 0 kB on disk.

**Code:**

```
### simple plot
reset session
set terminal png size 900,400
set output "myOutput.png"

set datafile separator ","
set title "Transaction/second graph"
set ylabel "Transactions"
set xlabel "Seconds"
set key left top
set grid
plot "output.txt" using 1:2 with lines lw 2 lt 3 title 'tps'
set output    # close output file and swith back to default
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also need to tell gnuplot how the input time is formatted. `set format x "%s"` just means how the numbers will be formatted in the graph.

To tell gnuplot the time is given in seconds, use

```
set timefmt "%s"
```